# How to get pip3 to work on Linux

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, pip

I successfully installed Python 3.5.2 on my CentOS 6.5 system. I'm trying to get pip to work with this version of Python to be able to install some modules.

When I run `$ pip3 install ...` it says command not found.

I also tried to run:

```
$ sudo yum install python3-pip
```

but that just returns: `No package python3-pip available.`

I also did:

```
$ python3 get-pip.py
```

But it says:

```
zipimport.ZipImportError: can't decompress data; zlib not available
```

How am I supposed to get this working?

Comment: running `python -m ensurepip`?

Comment: "No module named ensurepip" when running "python -m ensurepip", "Ignoring ensurepip failure: pip 8.1.1 requires SSL/TLS" when trying "python3 -m ensurepip" is what's returned

Comment: As far as I know, that version of Python already includes pip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> zipimport.ZipImportError: can't decompress data; zlib not available

Then get ZLIB

```
yum install zlib-devel
```

> pip 8.1.1 requires SSL/TLS

Then get SSL...

```
yum install openssl-devel
python3 -m ensurepip
```

In any case, since the pip version is being printed, you already have pip installed, you just need to determine why it won't run

Comment: After installation of ssl (which seemed to work) the second command you posted still returns "Ignoring ensurepip failure: pip 8.1.1 requires SSL/TLS"

Comment: Hmm. Got that instructions from here.  https://techglimpse.com/python-pip-ssl-tls-error-solution/

Comment: I installed python again after installing SSL, now have pip3, thanks!